# could not convert string to float "price"

Tags: python

when I run the program this has been popping up. could not convert string to float. I tried to look it up but I couldn't find anything.

here's the code:

```
f = open("ticket.txt",'r')
s=f.read()
lines=s.split("\n")
priceMax=0
priceMin=9999
total=0
for line in lines:
cols=line.split(" ")
price=(float)(cols[1])
total=total+price
if(price>priceMax):
   priceMax=price
if(price<priceMin):
   priceMin=price
f.close()
f=open("output.txt",'w')
f.write("*******************************************\n")
f.write(" TICKET REPORT\n")
f.write("*******************************************\n\n")
f.write("There are " + str(len(lines)) + " tickets in the database.\n\n")
f.write("Maximum Ticket price is $" + str(priceMax) + "\n")
f.write("Minimum Ticket price is $" + str(priceMin) + "\n")
f.write("Average Ticket price is $" + str(total / len(lines)) + "\n\n")
f.write("Thank you for using our ticket system!\n\n")
f.write("*******************************************\n")

f.close()
print("File Created sucessfully")
```

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question. Fix the indentation of the code.

Comment: apparently this code `(float)("5")` works on the terminal, so c style casting is supported in python.

Comment: `(float)("5")` isn't really C-style casting. It's more like `(round)(5.1)`: it parenthesizes the function/class call. It does happen to end up the same, but it's confusing, and bad style in Python.

Comment: You're reading lines from a file of which we don't know the content. And then the content (line by line, one single column) is converted to a float. Obviously, at least one of your input file lines has a non-float in that column, but we can't help you there, without seeing the offending input line(s).

Comment: @Suleman Not really. The "(float)" evaluates to "float" first, then the following parentheses are evaluated as calling "float" which does a type conversion.

Answer (score 0):

What's the error that's shown?

I think the issue is that you have started the list with `cols[1]` instead of `cols[0]`.

Also the indentation is wrong here.

```
for line in lines:
    cols=line.split(" ")
    price=(float)(cols[0])
    total=total+price

    if(price>priceMax):
       priceMax=price

    if(price<priceMin):
       priceMin=price
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, indentation is important in Python.  You must be consistent.

This "cast" `(float)` evaluates to, basically, the `float()` function, and then you call it, so that's not the problem.  More canonical is `f = float("123.45")`.  Now, this will throw a `ValueError` exception if there's an invalid number passed, so, you might want to catch this, so you can find out where the problem is.  Along the lines of:

```
s = "123.baboom"
try:
    f = float(s)
except ValueError as e:
    print("Oh, no, got an exception:", e)
    print("The offending string was: ", s)
```